# Differences in Gmail on BlackBerry to iPhone?

Tags: email, gmail

I've been using Gmail on my iPhone happily for a while. Now for a friend I need to set up Gmail on a BlackBerry.

From reading up it seems you have to enable IMAP for the Gmail account. I thought that POP downloads emails from the server where as IMAP does not. I'm confused as on my iPhone, when I read an email it's marked as read on the server (which I see when I use webmail or Mac mail to look at the same email account). However I never turned on IMAP for my account. I went through my iPhone's default email set up, so is it in fact using POP?

If so, what are the behavioural differences that my friend using IMAP on BlackBerry will experience compared to my iPhone set up, which seems nice and intuitive.

Comment: Suggest this is migrated to superusers rather than closed.

Comment: [Super User FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) expressly prohibits questions about devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple worked closely with Google and other email providers to enable easy 'it just works' integration and setup on the iPhone. So, while GMail the iPhone uses IMAP it doesn't require the third party IMAP security setting to be enabled to function.

Blackberry haven't been involved with Google/GMail, so far as I can tell, but use the same protocol so setting aside differences in the UI the two should work in an identical fashion.